# PhpStorm and WSL integration

Tags: gulp, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to integrate WSL in PhpStorm because I want to use WSL for all my `Gulp tasks` and the `Terminal` in PhpStorm.

The reason for this is that my Gulp tasks are using `Rsync` which is not available for Windows.

These steps are the steps I've gone through so far :

1. Install WSL (Ubuntu 18.04).
2. Install PhpStorm without changing any of the default settings.
3. Install everything I need in WSL (npm, git, php, gulp etc.).
4. In PhpStorm settings I added `C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe` in `Settings > Tools > Terminal`

The `Terminal` in the bottom of PhpStorm is indeed using WSL. I checked this by executing `lsb_release -a`.

Next thing I did was execute the gulp task *manually* **in** PhpStorm terminal. This worked. As it was using WSL.

#### The problem/question:

As soon as I use the Gulp window in PhpStorm to activate the tasks it doesn't work anymore. It will give me the error

> 'rsync' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Meaning it doesn't use the right terminal for running these tasks? Is there a way to get this to work?

[image: Image of PhpStorm Gulp task window + the error]

[image: Gulp task run config]

Comment: What Node.js interpreter is used when running Gulp tasks? It should be WSL Node.js interpreter to make this work.

Comment: @Oksana Very good that you mentioned this. I have now set it up to use WSL Node.js interpreter. Yet, this doesn't solve my issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you please show complete new console output?

Comment: Also, where in WSL rsync is installed (please run `which rsync`)? How is it run in gulp task? 
How PATH looks like in WSL (to learn it please run `console.log(process.env.PATH)` in gulp task)?

Comment: @Oksana Sure, here is the output from PhpStorm along with some settings. https://imgur.com/a/GI67WtY.

Comment: @Oksana As you can see in my previous message the path is `/usr/bin/rsync`. This is also the result I get when running `which rsync` in WSL.

Comment: Could you please also show your run configuration (right click on the task - edit)?

Also, click on the folded command 'gulp download_images` in the console. How does the full command look like?

Comment: @Oksana I have added a picture for the configuration. Also, folded command isn't actually a folded command, and therefore cannot be opened.

Comment: Ok, I now see it was using the wrong node there.. Is there no place where you can globally assign the right node version to phpstorm? Also, I changed it now and I don't get any errors, But the gulp task seems to be stuck in phpstorm. I am waiting for 10 minutes and it just doesn't finish the task.

Comment: Please check that you have set WSL Node as Node Interpreter in `Settings | Languages&Frameworks | Node.js and NPM`. Usually, it's enough.
Also, check that correct Node is set in the template Gulp run/debug configuration.